# Count rows by parent table attribute field

Tags: php, mysql

I have two Mysql tables (SQLfiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2aa8da/4)):

### Table domini

idD(int)  |  host(varchar)  | category(int)

### Table banners

idB(int)  |  titolo(varchar)  | skDomini(int)

The banners table is related with domini using a foreign key (skDomini) that references domini.idD in a non-identyfing relationship.

I would like count all banners per category and store the results in an array.

My actual code works but: is there one single query to achieve this without using a foreach loop?

I'm using this php code:

```
 $categs = array(1 => 'sport', 2 => 'organizations', 3 => 'art', 4 => 'food & wine'); //missing some categories to simplify ..
 $arr = array();

 foreach($categs as $key => $val) {
     $sel = $db->query("SELECT COUNT(B.idB) AS cnt FROM banners B 
                        JOIN domini D ON
                        D.idD = B.skDomini
                        WHERE D.category = $key");
     $row = $sel->fetch();
     $arr[$key] = $row->cnt;

 }
```

Comment: SQL Server is an unrelated database. Try to be careful when tagging.

Comment: **WARNING**: This has some severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) because user data is used inside the query. Whenever possible use **prepared statements**. These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.
**NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or any user data directly in your query.

Comment: This is pseudo mysql code . In my project i use prepared statements Thanks

Comment: That's good to hear, but it's usually best to include that anyway. It shows you're paying attention to the little things.

Comment: Doing `COUNT(...)` without a corresponding `GROUP BY` is probably the issue here. "Banners per category" means grouping on category. That avoids N queries here inside the loop.

Comment: Check this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/168dfc/1 . I changed one of your values, so don't worry when the results aren't what you were thinking they'd be.

Comment: I've tried this query and it seems ok:  

SELECT D.category, COUNT(B.idB) FROM banners B 
LEFT JOIN domini D ON
D.idD = B.skDomini
WHERE (D.category > 0) GROUP BY D.category; 

I also have updated fiddle. GROUP BY is the solution.. thanks @tadman

Comment: [updated fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2aa8da/39)